# GlassMapper Parent Item

Tags: glass-mapper

In my GlassMapper model I'm getting the children of the current page using the following declaration:

```
public IEnumerable<BasePage> Subpages => GetChildren<BasePage>(TemplateId);
```

Is there a similar method I could use to get the properties of the parent of the current page into a BasePage model? I can use the template ID of this item to get the Sitecore.Data.Items.Item parent of the page, but when I have this item I've been unable to convert it back into the BasePage model.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `[SitecoreParent]` attribute for that:

```
[SitecoreParent]
public virtual BasePage Parent { get; set; }
```

It is also mentioned in the Tutorial 17 (http://www.glass.lu/mapper/sc/tutorials/tutorial17)

Comment: Yep, this is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: to get parent of parent ?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've come up with up to this point. It's working for me, but I'm unsure if there is a more direct way to grab the parent item:

```
public virtual BasePage getParent()
{
    ISitecoreContext context = SitecoreContext.GetFromHttpContext();
    return context.Cast<BasePage>(Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(this.Id.ToString()).Parent);
}
```